# Setting layout of my menu object

Tags: java, jbutton, grid-layout, jmenu

I cannot set my new windows layout. I have a menu and submenus. I have an action listener on my submenu which directs me to new window. The problem is I cannot set it to given layout. Here's my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Converter extends JFrame
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private MoneyDetails convertMe = new MoneyDetails();
    private JLabel tlLabel = new JLabel("     Amount of TL");
    private JLabel dollarsLabel = new JLabel("Amount of Dollars");
    private JTextField tlField = new JTextField("0.0");
    private JTextField dollarsField = new JTextField("0.0");
    private JButton tlButton = new JButton("Convert to $");
    private JButton dollarsButton = new JButton("<<< Convert to TL");
    private JButton setRates = new JButton("Set Rates");

    private JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar(); // Window menu bar
    public Converter(String title) {
        setTitle(title);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setJMenuBar(menuBar); // Add the menu bar to the window
        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File"); // Create File menu
        JMenu elementMenu = new JMenu("Elements"); // Create Elements menu
        JMenuItem subTest = new JMenuItem("Test");

        // Here is the problem
        subTest.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){     
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent){
                Converter convert = new Converter();

                GridLayout expLay = new GridLayout(2,2,12,6);
                convert.setLayout(expLay);
                convert.getLayout();
                convert.doLayout();
                convert.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        menuBar.add(fileMenu); // Add the file menu
        menuBar.add(elementMenu); // Add the element menu
        fileMenu.add(subTest);
    }

    public Converter()
    {
        JPanel dataPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 2, 12, 6));
        dataPanel.add(tlLabel);

        dataPanel.add(dollarsLabel);
        dataPanel.add(tlField);
        dataPanel.add(dollarsField);
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.add(tlButton);
        buttonPanel.add(dollarsButton);
        Container container = this.getContentPane();
        container.add(dataPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        container.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        tlButton.addActionListener(new TLConverter());
        dollarsButton.addActionListener(new DollarsConverter());
        buttonPanel.add(setRates);
    }

    private class TLConverter implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            try
            {
                String input = tlField.getText();
                double tl = Double.parseDouble(input);
                convertMe.setTL(tl);
                double dollars = convertMe.getDollars();
                dollarsField.setText(String.format("%.2f", dollars));
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter the amount that will be converted.");
            }
        }
    }

    private class DollarsConverter implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            String input = dollarsField.getText();
            double dollars = Double.parseDouble(input);
            convertMe.setDollars(dollars);
            double tl = convertMe.getTL();
            tlField.setText(String.format("%.2f", tl));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        System.out.println("bbb");
        Converter window = new Converter("Para Dönüstürücü"); 
        System.out.println("aaa");
        window.setBounds(30, 30, 300, 300);
        window.setVisible(true);
    /*  Converter theGUI = new Converter();
        theGUI.setTitle("TL to $ or $ to TL Converter");
        theGUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        theGUI.pack();
        theGUI.setVisible(true); */
    }
}
```

Problem lies in the constructor with a `String` argument: `subTest.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){...`

Comment: Please elaborate on what _exactly_ doesn't work. What are you trying to do, what do you expect and what do you get instead? You should also not call `doLayout()` directly but let Swing do that for you.

Comment: What's the problem again?  Seems to pretty much work for me (after adding in a fake `MoneyDetails` class).  I did get a small window pop up when pressing "Test" - is the smallness your issue?  Try calling `pack()` at the end of the default constructor if so...

Comment: I have my menu, and submenu. When I click on my submenu, I have a new window.And I want to set its GridLayout. I've tried many ways but none of them worked. Here is the screenshoots, Thats how it looks now : http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg189/scaled.php?server=189&filename=screenshot20120502at202.png&res=landing ,  and Thats how I want it to look like http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg703/scaled.php?server=703&filename=screenshot20120502at202.png&res=landing

Comment: Oh my godness, How could I forget the pack().. Not even checked it if it does exist or not. Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem.  I made an answer out of it to grab some more rep. :)

Comment: With a great pleasure :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a call to `pack()` in the default constructor.